# Can I use paypal android sdk outside US?

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway

I have integrated paypal android sdk in my application.
Can user make payment through this sdk in USA and other countries depending upon their local currency ?

Answer (score 2):

The new Mobile SDKs are available in all countries where REST APIs are available as mentioned in the FAQs. Please see below the list of countries and country specific policies/process.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Paypal supports multiple countries and currencies. So there is no issue in using paypal for payments. For List of countries check this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/